# Trying to preserve carriage returns when using <cfpdfform>

Tags: xml, pdf, coldfusion, cfpdfform

I'm pushing HTML forms data into PDFs using the `<cfpdfform>` tag and XML data created from the HTML post with `XMLFormat()`.

For the life of me, I can't preserve carriage returns.

My strategy has been to replace the CRLF ( `chr(13) & chr(10)` ) in the post with a character string that survives the `XMLFormat()` and appropriately controls the text layout in the PDF.

I've tried HTML, HTML Entities, \n, etc.  The *only* string that had any affect on the output other than to appear exactly as sent, was this `&#x000D;&#x000A;`

Unfortunately, that string (or individually either character of it) removes some of the surrounding text.  But it *was* the only string that had any affect.

How do I preserve carriage returns?  Does anyone know?

Thanks for any input you may have.

Comment: When you first submit your form, is the data plain text or xml?  What are the relevant ascii values?

Comment: It posts plain text.  In the text, that CRLF is a char 13 and a char 10, as you would expect.  But these characters do not make it through the XMLFormat() function and are stripped.  I can easily replace them prior to XMLFormat but can't find a replacement that carries through to the PDF field as a NEWLINE.

Comment: Create a variable with a value of `'1' & chr(13) & chr(10) & '2'` and work with that.  For the strings in your question, try doubling up the octopthorps.

Comment: Octothorps!  Had to look that up.  Actually, I have been doubling them and they do wind up properly in the XML as a single.  I think CF would throw an error otherwise. Thanks for your ideas.  Unfortunately the CR and LF are still stripped, leaving just the "12" in the PDF form field.

Comment: (Edit) The docs usually just call it a pound sign. How did you determine the CF code is removing the new lines? Is it possible they are really being passed to the form field, just not displayed/interpreted properly. Any chance you could post a repro case?

Comment: Or "hash"...  I'm certain the CR and LF are being stripped by the XMLFormat() function because they are illegal XML and they are not in the output.  Also, when I replace them, the replacements show up in the PDF field. Repro case a good idea.  I'll put one together. thanks

Comment: Have you tried something silly like wrapping the form data in `<![CDATA[#form.var#]]>`? Just a wild guess.